# Specifying different momentJS locales per React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have two components where I'd like to apply separate locals. For example:

**Component A (Main)**

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime: {
        ...
        ss: '%d seconds',
        mm: '%d minutes',
    },
});
```

**Component B (Modal)**

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime: {
        ...
        ss: '%ss',
        mm: '%dm',
    },
});
```

My concern is that opening the modal (component B) will override the global locale settings, and once the user returns to the main view (component A) the UI would be different.

Is it possible to apply locales on a per-component basis?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale for individual `moment` instances. From the [momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/):

```
moment.locale('en'); // default the locale to English
var localLocale = moment();

localLocale.locale('fr'); // set this instance to use French
localLocale.format('LLLL'); // dimanche 15 juillet 2012 11:01
moment().format('LLLL'); // Sunday, July 15 2012 11:01 AM
```